# Sendgrid and iCalendar: missing Yes/No/Maybe buttons in event Gmail client

Tags: java, spring, calendar, sendgrid, icalendar

I am using SendGrid for sending Calendar events. The attendee successfully receives the event, but there is no action buttons like: Yes, No, Maybe:

[image]

The calendar event looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//My Service//My Service//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:MEETING
ORGANIZER;CN=MyService.com:MAILTO:support@test.com
ATTENDEE:MAILTO:user1@gmail.com
DTSTAMP:20210628T171803Z
DTSTART:20210628T171803Z
DTEND:20210628T191803Z
SUMMARY:Interview event
UID:e55c3e16-337f-4a44-97e7-5ffca790b93e
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Does any one know which [iCalendar](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2445) component/property I should use so the buttons become visible on the event?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing a similar problem. I have already tried `RSVP=TRUE` for `ATTENDEE`

Comment: @jennyjenkins, no I didn't find the solution.

Comment: From what I saw, it doesn't have anything to do with `RSVP=TRUE`. What my mistake was that I was trying to create an event in the past, i.e. before the current time and date. The event gets created fine, but obviously doesn't ask the attendee for `Yes/No/Maybe`.